# Folding at home, NVIDIA GPU stuck in Failed/Ready/Disabled state

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, gpu

I wasn't able to fold with GPU for some reason ...

Quick setup.

1. Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (bionic) with third party drivers for NVIDIA (see https://pastebin.com/raw/vGrr7GXu for most packages)
2. Installed latest fahclient, fahcontrol from https://foldingathome.org/start-folding (similar to https://foldingathome.org/support/faq/installation-guides/linux)
3. Rebooted

`18:33:12:WU01:FS02:Sending unit results: id:01 state:SEND error:FAILED project:14907 run:87 clone:0 gen:231 core:0x22 unit:0x0000012d81d59d695f526030ac6fce05`

`19:09:39:WU01:FS02:Sending unit results: id:01 state:SEND error:FAILED project:13429 run:9209 clone:8 gen:2 core:0x22 unit:0x0000000312bc7d9a0000000023f90008`

`19:30:39:WARNING:WU01:FS02:FahCore returned: WU_STALLED (127 = 0x7f)`

`19:30:39:WARNING:WU01:FS02:Too many errors, failing`

`19:30:39:WU01:FS02:Sending unit results: id:01 state:SEND error:FAILED project:13429 run:9255 clone:16 gen:2 core:0x22 unit:0x0000000312bc7d9a0000000024270010`

Full log for FS02: https://pastebin.com/T4F2Ew64

I can switch GPU slot to "on idle" and back (it will show up as "Ready") but it logs it will continue to download and fail (silently to the user, because status is always "Ready").

I changed "cause preference" from "COVID-19" to "Any" and created new GPU slot (without reboot). I can see "Disabled" in GPU slot. I got this log (just one message for GPU slot):

```
*********************** Log Started 2020-11-30T18:28:45Z ***********************
******************************* Date: 2020-12-01 *******************************
******************************* Date: 2020-12-01 *******************************
04:52:32:WARNING:FS01:No CUDA or OpenCL 1.2+ support detected for GPU slot 01: gpu:-1:-1.  Disabling.
```

I see the same "Disabled" status after reboot.

**Updates below:**

Same status "Ready" GPU with 0% progress and many attempts after 10 days: https://pastebin.com/AcuPDfXx.

Now stuck with "Failed" state (full log https://pastebin.com/AckYSBVN).

Comment: Delete the GPU in FaH, then add it back. I had something similar happen yesterday.

Comment: @ajgringo619 "No CUDA or OpenCL 1.2+ support detected for GPU slot"

Comment: Sorry about that. You need to stop, then restart the FAHClient. It *should* automatically find cuda and OpenCl.

Comment: @ajgringo619 even rebooting didn't help me. Now trying to get CUDA from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Comment: Unable to just "sudo sh cuda_11.1.1_455.32.00_linux.run": "Existing package manager installation of the driver found. It is strongly recommended that you remove this before continuing."

Comment: Please ask here as well: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: What distro are you running? How did you initially install the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Installed 3rd party driver during installation. Current "nvidia-*" selections: https://pastebin.com/amfSZE4Z Not sure if I need something else...

Comment: nvidia-smi reports NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fold with GPU again after latest NVIDIA driver and Linux kernel update. Magically resolved for me.

https://stats.foldingathome.org/project?p=14911, 2% log: https://pastebin.com/XbU03FHn

I'm not sure if I can fold https://stats.foldingathome.org/project?p=13439 on GPU...